# Column Property AutoMapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, automapping

There is o possibility to create a convention for Column naming:

I have this piece of code:

```
public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
{
    var result = AutoPersistenceModel.MapEntitiesFromAssemblyOf<User>()
        .Where(GetAutoMappingFilter)
        .WithConvention(GetConventions);

    return result;
}

private bool GetAutoMappingFilter(Type t)
{
    return
        t.GetInterfaces().Any(
            x => x.IsGenericType && (x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>)));
}


private static void GetConventions(Conventions conventions)
{
    conventions.GetPrimaryKeyNameFromType = type => type.Name.ToLower() + "_id";
    conventions.FindIdentity = type => type.Name.ToLower() == "id";
    conventions.GetTableName = type =>
        {
            if (!type.Name.Contains("Lookup"))
            {
                return Inflector.Net.Inflector.Pluralize(type.Name).ToLower();
            }
            return Inflector.Net.Inflector.Underscore(type.Name)
                .Replace("lookup", "lu").ToLower();
        };
    conventions.IsBaseType = DontMapAsJoinedSubclassTypesInheritedFrom;
    conventions.GetForeignKeyNameOfParent = type => Inflector.Net.Inflector.Underscore(type.Name) + "_id";
    conventions.GetForeignKeyName = type => Inflector.Net.Inflector.Underscore(type.Name) + "_id";
    conventions.OneToManyConvention = m => m.Cascade.All();

}


private static bool DontMapAsJoinedSubclassTypesInheritedFrom(Type arg)
{
    var derivesFromEntity = arg == typeof(Entity);
    var derivesFromEntityWithTypedId = arg.IsGenericType &&
        (arg.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityWithTypedId<>));
    return derivesFromEntity || derivesFromEntityWithTypedId;
}
```

and an Entity class

```
public class Organisation : EntityWithTypedId<int>
{
    public virtual Organisation Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual LookOrganisationType OrganisationType { get; set; }
    [DomainSignature]
    public virtual string OrganisationName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string Postcode { get; set; }
    public virtual LookupCountry Country { get; set; }
    public virtual string TelNo { get; set; }
    public virtual string FaxNo { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual User Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateAmended { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I want to have a column for, let's say TelNo like tel_no.
So the Convention is if Property contains capital letter in the middle ti should be underscored. Inflector.Net.Inflector.Underscore works fine. But I do not know how to write the convention.

Somethig like:

```
(conventions.GetPropertyName = type => Inflector.Net.Inflector.Underscore(type.ColumnName))
```

Thanks